# Is there some method to fix the scale of an axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some math calculations and I want to visualize the result of this calculations. So I want to see changes of some line with time. And axes scale should be constant in whole period of time for best understanding of results. But in my program there are changes of axes scale:
[initial frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjxP6.png), [last frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzpPC.png)

There is some part of my `redraw` function:

```
def redraw(k):
    # math calculations
    ax.clear()
    xlocs = np.linspace(ball.r1, env.r2, 5)
    ylocs = np.linspace(env.t0, ball.t0, 5)
    ax.set_xticks(xlocs)
    ax.set_yticks(ylocs)
    # creating the line
```

So I create arrays in which there are marks which I want to see on axes. But functions `ax.set_xticks()` and `ax.set_yticks()` don't work or I misunderstand how they work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_yticks` sets the *positions* of the ticks on the y-axis. In order to set the size of the y-axis itself you want to use [`set_ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim):

```
ax.set_ylim(min(ylocs), max(ylocs))
```